# Multiple sorting on tables

Tags: google-app-maker

I have 2 tables, which has one - many relation ship. The child table has 4 columns (Let say, A, B, C, D)

A - Table column
B - Foreign key column
C - Foreign key column
D - Table column

Requirement is to sort the data by A, B,then by C when displaying records

I tried with query script but not working. (Relation data source doesn't load)

I tried with specifying the sort field on Relations tab (Sorting work only for table column, fk columns are not displayed)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: At this time App Maker only supports sorting of one column when a table is the direct relation table of another.  If you wanted to accomplish sorting by relationships and multiple columns your relation datasource should be its own datasource vs a relation and then reload this datasource each time the item changes in your main datasource.

Comment: Thank you @MarkusMalessa
I was able to achieve this by manually loading the datasource. I added the query script as below,

    var contractDataSource=[];
    query.filters.IsActive._equals=true;
    query.filters.myDS._equals = query.parameters.ID;
    query.sorting.Date._ascending();
    query.sorting.my_FK1.code._ascending();
    query.sorting.my_FK1.Location._ascending();
    contractDataSource = query.run();
    return contractDataSource;

Then parameter was added as ID. Value for the ID is set on the UI.

   app.datasources.myDS.query.parameters.ID=[Value for the ID]